# Introduction of critically endangered South Asian species to South America

Tags: ecology

I have in mind in particular orangutans but don't want the question to be that specific, so the answers about other species will be equally welcome.

Orangutans are endangered or critically endangered due to the rapid and dramatic loss of their natural habitat (tropical rainsforests of Sumatra and Borneo).

1. Have there been attempts to introduce orangutans to, say, the Amazon rainforest as a species preservation measure?
2. Was there any public discussion of (1)?
3. If the answer to (1-2) is no, is there any obvious reason for that?
   No chance of taking root? Or there's a big risk of threatening the existing ecosystem once they take hold?

Comment: Highly Doubt 1 and 2. Introduction of non-native species can adversely affect local ecosystems. Might endanger or eliminate several native species.  Abingdon tortoise went extinct because of mere goats